# Hiding ajax call from firebug

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a project where i'm calling a php file from jquery ajax.Inside the php file i have a curl call to a rest API to have some data.This data flow cannot be altered i.e from jquery i call the php file then from php file the api will be called.Now i have to prevent displaying the url in the firebug console when the ajax call is triggered.Any idea how can i achieve this? Here is the code i used for calling the php file.

```
$.getJSON("file.php",function(data) {
    console.log("hello"+data);
});
```

Comment: You can't.  If the user's browser is making the request, the user can see it.

Comment: i found something on net that a JSONP request doesnot show the request URL on console,Is there any way i can use the JSONP request?

Comment: Security through obscurity isn't the answer!

Comment: JSONP requests DO show in the console. Look under scripts.

Comment: @David that's an answer ...

Comment: Make the request using your server before you even return the page to the client. Otherwise, if you initiate the request from the client, the user can see it.

Comment: Yes i found that...So theres no way i guess..

Comment: Why can't the user see the URL is the question, what is the reason behind hiding it?

Answer (score 5):

> Now i have to prevent displaying the url in the firebug console when the ajax call is triggered.

Sorry, not possible.  If the user's web browser is making a request, the user can see it.  Even if you manage to somehow hide it from the web browser, they can still see it in any number of other tools.  Any request that comes from the user's machine can be inspected by the user.

If you absolutely *need* to make this happen, then you need to write a custom client and perform encrypted communication between that client and your server.

Now to the real question... *why* should this be hidden from the user?  If the user shouldn't see the data, then why is the request being made client-side in the first place?  Just make the request from server-side code and keep the data server-side.  If the user *should* see the data, then what's the problem?  If the user only shouldn't see the URL but should see the data, get the data server-side and only show the data to the user.

If you have a public URL which is providing requestors with sensitive information and you don't want anybody to know what that URL is, you have a security problem.  As mentioned in a comment above, security through obscurity is no security at all.